# How do I get reference of a Fragment in the parent Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing this method:

```
homeFragment.mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(MainActivity.this,homeFragment.membersList);
```

`MainActivity` is the activity which is having fragment `HomeFragment`. If we want this method for mainActivity itself then above method is right but if we want this method for fragment but the method is in MainActivity then what to pass?

I want something like:

```
homeFragment.mAdapter = new MembersAdapter(HomeFragment.this,homeFragment.membersList);
```

The method is in MainActivity.

Comment: use getActivity() instead of HomeFragment.this.

Comment: @user3559670 I cant use it here because I want this code in mainActivity not in fragment see question again.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create one method in fragment like

**setAdapterFromActivity()**

then you can get current running fragment in activity by below code

```
 Fragment f=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout_id);
 if (f instanceof homeFragment) {
        ((homeFragment) f).setAdapterFromActivity();
    }
```

Comment: I didnt get that at all